# Uploading file image Using CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

in my view, I used `form_open_multipart()`, and I have:

```
<input type="file" name="user_photo" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
```

I have a configuration in my controller like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './resources/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '0';
$config['max_width'] = '0';
$config['max_height'] = '0';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('user_photo')) {
echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
} else {
echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->upload->data());
}
```

But, when I try to upload image file with filetype *.jpg, I've an error like this: `The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`
Is there any wrong with my configuration,.?
thanks,.

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter are you using and which version of PHP is the web server you're experiencing the problem with using?

Comment: are you using : $config['file_name'] in your configuration..?

Comment: @stealthyninja I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and PHP 5.3.0,.

Comment: @Sudhir no, I just put the configuration like above,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web server is using PHP v5.2.x and you're using CodeIgniter 2.1.0, downgrade back to CodeIgniter 2.0.3 and the upload problem should go away.

The guilty line of code that creates this issue in CodeIgniter 2.1.0 is

```
$this->file_type = @mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
```

in `/system/libraries/Upload.php`. See the list of CodeIgniter **[open issues](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/search?q=mime_content_type&state=open&assignee=)** for more information.

Comment: Yeah, I've try it in CodeIgniter 2.0.3, and it's work,. thanks,.